# Easy way to cancel current NSXMLParser parsing operation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

Alright.

Lets say i have a `UITextField` where a user can input an url such as:

```
http://foo.bar/foo/bar.asmx
```

Now, if the application is fed the right URL, it will respond with an `NSData` with a bytesize of around 450-700 depending on the returning values, the values differ between users. The call takes around a second or so, and the `NSXMLParser` parses the data within a second aswell.

But whenever we input for example:

```
http://apple.com/foo/bar.asmx
```

We recieve an `NSData` with a bytesize of around 9700. And the parser parses this data through infinity. And i have no idea how to throw the proper errormessage when the user has made input to an invalid url resulting in the `NSXMLParser` parses for infinity.

We tried using this.

in the

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser shouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
[xmlParser parse];
[self performSelector:@selector(timeOutMyParser:) withObject:nil afterdelay:15];

[xmlParser release];
[connection release];
[myData release];

}
```

Now, what happens with this code is that the performSelector is never executed since it's forever running the parsing.

So to summarize:

In order to reduce the number of errors our users can create, we need to stop our current NSXMLParser parser operations if they take to long.

Is there any EASY way to cancel the current parsing operation?

Comment: The selector is never fired since the parser is parsing on the main thread, and the main thread is blocked by parsing. What I do is put the parsing in a NSOperation, put that NSOperation on an NSOperationQueue which will make it a threaded application. Then you could invoke abortParsing from within the thread or the parser delegate methods themselves.

Comment: Umm okay, do you have any resources or examples about how i might go about stopping the thread if the parsingoperation takes to long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `[xmlParser parse]` was blocking the main thread, locking everything.

So instead of

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser shouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [self performSelector:@selector(timeOutMyParser:) withObject:nil afterdelay:15];

    [xmlParser release];
    [connection release];
    [myData release];

    }
```

i did this.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]init];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser shouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(someFunction) withObject:xmlParser];

[xmlParser release];
[connection release];
[myData release];

}
```

Where `someFunction` is something like this.

```
-(void)someFunction:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];

[parser release];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually calling `[xmlParser parse]` returns a boolean value which will be *YES* if the parsing succeeded. Returns *NO* otherwise. So just receive the boolean value.

```
BOOL parserSucceeded = [xmlParser parse];
```

While parsing, if you get invalid data in your XML or if you want to stop the parsing upon a condition, you can cancel the parsing by calling

```
[parser abortParsing];
```

And you can check for the status and do appropriate actions.

```
BOOL parserSucceeded = [xmlParser parse];

if (parserSucceeded) {

    // Parser Succeeded

} else {

    // Parser Failed/Aborted
}
```

Comment: We cannot reach the parsersucceeded variable as the [xmlparser parse] statement starts the parser and it locks the main thread. And if the url is for example: apple.com the parsing operation takes forever. And crashes.

Comment: @Da_smokes, You can not determine whether the XML is valid or invalid by looking at the content of XML?

Comment: @Da_smokes, If so you can abort the parsing easily

Comment: No, because if i input an invalid URL, i never even reach the parser delegate methods, it's just stuck on [parser parse];

Comment: @Da_smokes, This seems strange. Did you print the data *NSLog* using `[NSString stringWithData:data]`? Does it print a valid XML string?