# NSXMLParser: Parse specifc elements based on another element

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am parsing the following XML with `NSXMLParser` but would like to only parse certain elements and attributes based on a unique element found in the XML and then abort the parse.

For example, my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<systems>
<system id="system1">
    <game title="game1">
        <checksums>
            <checksum value="checksumvalue1" />
        </checksums>
        <players>
            <player name="name1" description="description1" />
            <player name="name2" description="description2" />
        </players>
    </game>
</system>
```

I would like to be able to return all `players` in `game` based only on the value of `checksum`
So if I pass `checksumvalue1` to my method, I'd like to return only the `players` found in that one `game` node with the unique checksum. In the XML, there will be other games with checksums but checksums will always be unique.

So far I have some basic parser code to just read the element and attributes from the checksum value, but I don't know where to go from there. I'm also wondering if `NSXMLNode` with XPath's makes more sense to accomplish this.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"checksum"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"value"] isEqualToString:@"checksumvalue1"]) {
    NSString *checksumValue = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSLog(@"value: %@", checksumValue);

// print players in only one game node that contains the unique checksum value
   }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of whether you've found the checksum yet and all the players you have encountered. You need a boolean `foundGameChecksum` and an `NSMutableArray* players`. Don't forget to `players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"checksum"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"value"] isEqualToString:@"checksumvalue1"]) {
        NSString *checksumValue = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"value"];
        NSLog(@"value: %@", checksumValue);

        foundGameChecksum = YES;
        // print players in only one game node that contains the unique checksum value
    } else if(foundGameChecksum && [elementName isEqualToString:@"player"]) {
        [players addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if(foundGameChecksum && [elementName isEqualToString:@"players"]) {
        [parser abortParsing]; // Stop parsing
    }
}
```

Then after `[parser parse];` is executed you will have the players in `players`

I.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<systems>
    <system id="system1">
        <game title="game1">
            <checksums>
                <checksum value="checksumvalue1" /> <!-- Found. Start adding -->
            </checksums>
            <players>
                <player name="name1" description="description1" /> <!-- Add -->
                <player name="name2" description="description2" /> <!-- Add -->
            </players> <!-- Stop adding -->
        </game>
    </system>
</systems>
```

Comment: One thing, is there any where I need to abortParsing after it's already found all its players? Looks like it'll still parse through the entire XML even after it's found players and added them all to the array.

Comment: Found an answer from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340731/easy-way-to-cancel-current-nsxmlparser-parsing-operation) `[parser abortParsing];` I have edited my answer.

Comment: I think at that step it breaks players getting added to the array

Comment: Sorry, introduced a bug. Should be fixed now.